# Bedeutung von "von enttäuscht"

Tags: vocabulary

Ich glaube, ich habe bei einem Interview das Folgende gehört:

> Da war ich auch von enttäuscht, weil ...

Und obwohl ich doch verstehen kann was gemeint war, kann man vielleicht eine genaue Erklärung dazu angeben, was so die Zusammenstellung von "von + Adjektiv" angeht? Ich möchte also die Rolle von dem "von" in diesem Beispielsatz besser verstehen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diese Redewendung, in der  "davon" in "da" und "von" getrennt wird, dürfte aus dem norddeutschen Sprachraum kommen. Ein ähnliches Phänomen ist

> Da nicht für

anstelle von "dafür nicht".

**Update:**

Es gibt weitere Beispiele dieser Art:

- damit: *Da* bin ich nicht *mit* einverstanden. (vgl. Olafants Kommentar)
- dagegen: *Da* bin aber wirklich *gegen*.
- davor: *Da* sei Gott *vor*.

Comment: Oder auch: *Da* bin ich nicht *mit* einverstanden.

Answer (score 6):

> Da war ich auch von enttäuscht.

ist im wesentlichen eine recht umgangssprachliche Version von

> Davon war ich auch enttäuscht.